# how to use bootreciever to set wallpaper after restarting device? (android, eclipse)

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'am making a wallpaper app but I had a problem that the wallpaper zooms in after restarting the phone so i tried using bootreciever and it does what I want it to do but it only works for the first image in the app and whenever i set any other image as wallpaper and the restart the device the image changes to the first image.

so does anyone know how to solve this problem, thanks in advance,

here is my MainActivity java:

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

```
static int tophone;
ImageView display;
public static Integer[] tophone2 = {
    R.drawable.iv1,R.drawable.iv2,R.drawable.iv3,R.drawable.iv4 };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tophone = R.drawable.iv1;
    display = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IView);
    ImageView image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv1);
    ImageView image2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv2);
    ImageView image3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv3);
    ImageView image4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv4);
    Button setWp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.setWp);

    Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(R.drawable.iv1_s).into(image1);
    Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(R.drawable.iv2_s).into(image2);
    Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(R.drawable.iv3_s).into(image3);
    Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(R.drawable.iv4_s).into(image4);


    image1.setOnClickListener(this);
    image2.setOnClickListener(this);
    image3.setOnClickListener(this);
    image4.setOnClickListener(this);
    setWp.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()){
    case R.id.iv1:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.iv1);
        tophone = tophone2[0];
        break;
    case R.id.iv2:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.iv2);
        tophone = tophone2[1];
        break;
    case R.id.iv3:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.iv3);
        tophone = tophone2[2];
        break;
    case R.id.iv4:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.iv4);
        tophone = tophone2[3];
        break;
    case R.id.setWp:
        Toast WpSet = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Wallpaper Set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

        SharedPreferences       sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("wallpaperapp",0);
        sharedPreferences.edit().putInt("position",0).commit();

        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics(); 
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        int height = metrics.heightPixels; 
        int width = metrics.widthPixels;
        Bitmap tempbitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), tophone);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(tempbitMap,width,height, true);
        WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(MainActivity.this); 
        wallpaperManager.setWallpaperOffsetSteps(1, 1);
        wallpaperManager.suggestDesiredDimensions(width, height);
        try {
          wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
          } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        WpSet.show();
        break;
}



}

}
```

and here is my BootReceiver java:

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private static final String TAG="BootReceiver";

@Override public void onReceive(Context context,Intent intent){
try{ 
    SharedPreferences       sharedPreferences =  context.getSharedPreferences("wallpaperapp",0);
int position= sharedPreferences.getInt("position", 0);
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
                int height = metrics.heightPixels;
                int width = metrics.widthPixels;
                Bitmap tempbitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),MainActivity.tophone2[position]);
                    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(tempbitMap,width,height, true);
                WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(context);
                wallpaperManager.setWallpaperOffsetSteps(1, 1);
                wallpaperManager.suggestDesiredDimensions(width, height);
                try {
                  wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
                  } catch (IOException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
                }
}catch(Exception e){
    Log.e(TAG,e.toString());
}
}
}
```

New BootReciever:

```
 public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
 private static final String TAG="BootReceiver";

 @Override public void onReceive(Context context,Intent intent){
 Intent in = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
 in.setFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    context.startActivity(in);
try{ 
    SharedPreferences       sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("wallpaperapp",MainActivity.tophone);
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
                int height = metrics.heightPixels;
                int width = metrics.widthPixels;
                Bitmap tempbitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),MainActivity.someDefault);
                    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(tempbitMap,width,height, true);
                WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(context);
                wallpaperManager.setWallpaperOffsetSteps(1, 1);
                wallpaperManager.suggestDesiredDimensions(width, height);
                try {
                  wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
                  } catch (IOException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
                }
}catch(Exception e){
    Log.e(TAG,e.toString());
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First change

```
SharedPreferences       sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("wallpaperapp",0);
```

To

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Whenever you change the wallpaper, you should save the resource id of the newly changed wallpaper to your shared preferences file, in your onClick method:

```
sharedPreference.edit().putInt(KEY, v.getId()).commit();
```

Note* The KEY variable in the putInt method is a constant which you will have to define, it is the name of the preference you want to change, you can give it the value "wallpaperapp"

Now you can simply retrieve the id when the phone has finished booting. Using the same KEY

```
int retrievedImageID = sharedPreference.getInt(KEY, someDefaultValue);
```

then simply set the image

```
display.setImageResource(retrievedImageID);
```

Here is android official documentation on sharedPreferences
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

your MainActivity will look something like ths:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
  // add these variables
  public static final String KEY = "wallpaperapp"
  private SharedPreferences sharedPreference;
  private int retrievedImageID;

  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //add these lines
    sharedPreference = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    changeWallpaper();
  }

public void onClick(View v) {
   switch(){}
   // add this line below the switch statement
   sharedPreference.edit().putInt(KEY, v.getId()).commit();
}
//add this method
public void changeWallpaper(){
   int someDefaultValue = R.id.iv1;
   retrievedImageID = sharedPreference.getInt(KEY, someDefaultValue);
   display.setImageResource(retrievedImageID);
}
```

And your boot receiver:

```
public void onReceive(Context context,Intent intent){
    // comment out the existing code in here
    // and add the following lines
    Intent in = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    // these flags must be set for the receiver to start the activity
    in.setFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    context.startActivity(in);
}
```

Comment: I'am really sorry but I don't quite understand what I should do, where should I type the code you provided in which java file my MainActivity or the BootReceiver?

Comment: you should save the resource id in your MainActivity inside your onClickMethod. The other two lines of code you could put it inside its own method and then in the BootReceiver you can then call this method

Comment: I'am getting an error with MODE_PRIVATE it cannot be resolved to a variable, and can't you provide me with an example using my code because I'am having a difficulty understanding your examples :) , sorry for all the trouble, I'am still a beginner

Comment: you have to import the context package:  import android.content.Context

Comment: the context package is Imported

Comment: Just to make sure these 2 lines:
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
sharedPreference.edit().putInt(KEY, v.getId()).commit();
are in the OnClick methodand where shouldI type the other 2 Lines

Comment: ok i edited the answer again.Note* for readability i left out your code so you will see the basic layout of where the new code will go

Comment: what should I replace position with in here:
 Bitmap tempbitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),MainActivity.tophone2[position]);

Comment: I changed it in the change wallpaper method to  int someDefaultValue = R.id.iv1;  retrievedImageID = sharedPreference.getInt(KEY, someDefaultValue);

Comment: I really don't understand anything

Comment: could you add how the final code will look like, please!!

Comment: Try commenting the existing code from the bootreceiver and only leave the new code

Comment: if that doesnt work, i will work on my own solution and post it